# Unit test for programs that uses influxdb

Tags: unit-testing, junit, influxdb, nosql

How could i write unit tests for an application that uses influx db as database without installing influxDB on system.

I want an embedded influxDB to start before tests, tests run, and close after tests.

Comment: What do you want to test? Which layer? The database layer? It will be hard to write meaningful integration tests without an actual database. Of course you can unittest it via mocking, sure, but that's not the important point for database tests. The whole rest? Simply encapsulate your database layer well enough and you can test it without any influx db via mocking or another db.

Comment: test with a db is not really a "unit test" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use a Docker image such as [tutum/influxdb](https://hub.docker.com/r/tutum/influxdb/). Only dependency in this setup is installing Docker.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I tackle the same issue while developing integration tests on a project.

I created a library for this purpose available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.apisense.embed.influx%7Cembed-influxDB%7C1.0.0%7Cjar) (the sources are available [on github](https://github.com/APISENSE/embed-influxDB)).

It enables to download and control an InfluxDB server directly from java.

Hope it helps.